# How to obtain a copy from a gridview?

Tags: .net, gridview

Im trying to get a completly data copy from a gridview, itryed clone(), tryed cast DataView from DataSouce, but always get nulls or cant get the data, please exists a way to copy data from gridview, modified it and then reload it? or modifyng directly some rows in the gridview? 
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the OnRowDataBound attribute to do something like this

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        //HeaderStuff
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ObjectTye objectType = (ObjectType)e.Row.DataItem;
        // and doing some stuff with the properties
        e.Row.Cells[0].Text = objectType.SomeProperty.ToString();
        LinkButton deleteLnk = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete");
        deleteLnk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return " + 
            "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this')");
        deleteLnk.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

    ObjectType objectType = new ObjectType();
    objectType.StringProperty = row.Cells[0].Text;
}
```

Comment: is possible to use that working with TemplateFields? i get a button and another column for checkbox

Comment: For RowCommand, you'll have to do some sort of data retrieval from the lists you used to populate the GridView

Comment: If I'm getting the right idea from your comments and posts, then I have a working version of what you want, in a sense, but you should have most of what you need to work out the solution yourself in the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is it you're trying to do with the data? Also is it a datagrid or a dataview and in what framework? If it's a datagrid that you're trying to copy the rows from,loop through the datagrid rows and add the row values to an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just bind the second grid the same source the first grid is bound to?

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = yourList;
DataGridView1.DataBind();
...
DataGridView2.DataSource = yourList; //or = DataGridView1.DataSource;
DataGridView2.DataBind();
```

As long as the data hasn't changed your should get an exact replica.

Comment: Im doing like it so check please:

IList<DetalleCita> testDetail = scvCitas.GetDetalleCosto(codeCarta, codigoEstudio, codeAseguradora, rucAseguradora);
            dgvEstudios.DataSource = testDetail;
            dgvEstudios.DataBind();

Comment: and im getting null when i try to get the datasource property from a gridview instance